# At which force will a hemp rope rip?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, string

I have  hemp rope which is hanging horizontally between two winches 140 m far away from each other.

Is it physically possible that the rope won't rip when I turn the winches so the rope will be even (or hanging only 20 cm in the middle)?

I am looking for a formula which considers the weight of the rope.

---

My attempt so far is this with a formula which doesn’t consider the weight of the rope, only additional weight in the middle of the rope.

[image]

```
F(o) = Tension in Newton
F(g) = weight in the middle of the rope
F(z) = tensile force for two ends
F(s) = initial tension

l = 140 m (Length of the distance between winches)
h = 0,2 m (maximal sag)
m = 0 kg (additional weight onto the rope)
F(s) = 6000 N
```

My problem is that I always get `18.000 N (1835.489178 kg)` since `F(z)` is always `0`.
[image]

Because with this formula my hemp rope won’t rip since a hemp rope with a diameter of `4,6 cm` (which weighs `1,5 kg/meter`) can hold `1870 kg`. So theoretically the rope can be tied horizontally.
But the rope itself weighs `210 kg` and if I assume only  `1,5 kg` in the middle of the rope I get `F(o) = 25.725 N (= 2620 kg)` - my rope rips.

> How can I consider the weight of the rope in the formula? Either the
>   total weight (as `210 kg`) or the weight of `1 m` rope (as `1,5 kg`).

Comment: Between two wenches?

Comment: winches --- sorry

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary

Comment: @AlbertAspect thank you for the link. But I am not a physicist at all; which formula do I have to use? I have no clue from the wiki-page. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "formula" to find the tension on the rope. You need to be able to solve an equation using numerical methods. You want to find $a$ from this equation:

$h=a(cosh(L/2a)-1)$

where $h$ is the vertical distance between the minimum height at the center of the rope and the edge of the rope, and $L$ is the length of the rope.

Once you find $a$ you can calculate the tension as $T=aw$, where $w$ is the weight of the rope per unit length.

Comment: Is gravity for the tension irrelevant? I found a formula `F=wg(h+a)` (w= weight of the rope per meter; g=gravity; h=sag; a as above; https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettenlinie_(Mathematik)#Beispiel) The unit would be Newton, right?

Comment: I cannot follow german, but the result looks fine to me on an overview, and seems essentially the same. First, in both solutions gravity appears in the same place (the g in my solution appears because your w is mass density and mine is weight density (a factor g of difference). Also, I made the approximation that h<<L, which should be good in your case, to simplify the solution,  but I did not realize that this approximation in the end seems not to be necessary.